What's the difference? $\nabla_\mu e_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho~\text{ and }~\partial_\mu e_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho~?$
What's the difference? $$\nabla_\mu e_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho~\text{ and }~\partial_\mu e_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho~?$$
In John Dirk Walecka's book 'Introduction to General Relativity', He told us that we can use connection to describe the change of basis vectors:
$$\partial_\mu e_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho$$
Then the difference of basis vector $e_\mu$ between points $x_0$ and $x_0+\delta x^\mu$ is:
$\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho \delta x^\mu$
Then conbine with the definition of metric field:
$$g_{\mu \nu}=e_\mu\cdot e_\nu$$
We will get the metric compatible equation:
\begin{align}
 \partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}&=(\partial_\rho e_\mu)\cdot e_\nu +e_\mu\cdot (\partial_\rho e_\nu)\nonumber\\
 &=\Gamma^\lambda_{\rho\mu }g_{\lambda\nu}+\Gamma^\lambda_{\rho\nu }g_{\mu\lambda}
\end{align}
But in many books, we find another formula:
$$\nabla_\mu e_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho$$
Then what is the difference between the two formulas?
And from this formula can we know the difference of the basis vector between $x_0$ and $x_0+\delta x^\mu$?

"But in many books, we find another formula:" -- what book(s)? What page(s)?

Which page in Walecka's book?

Without specifying the exact source, we can not really tell the difference. Nonetheless, $\partial_\mu$ is usually used as the extension of the three-dimensional $\nabla$ into the $(3+1)$-spacetime. Meanwhile, $\nabla_\mu$ is the covariant derivative used when curved spacetime is involved.

John Dirk's book page39,  3.64 the first formula. The second formula appears in Misner's Gravitation page259 10.13

The notation $\nabla_\mu e_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho$ is reasonable. MTW explain on several pages before p. 259 where it comes from. It has to do with the notation $\nabla_XY$ from DG where $X,Y$ are vector fields and $\nabla$ is a connection.

@hendlim
Yes, $\partial_\mu$ is just a partial derivative in a coordinate system, and $\nabla$ is a conbination of a partial derivative and a connection. So the two formula can not be right at the same time. So I wonder how to explain the two formula.

@Kurt G     So what is wrong about the first one? especially we can get metric compatible equation from the first formula.

Eq. (3.64) uses infinitesimal displacement $d$ not partial derivative $\partial_{\mu}$.

I have not yet thought about this deeply. My guess (confirmed by @Qmechanic's comment) is that $\partial_\mu e_\nu=\Gamma_{\mu \nu}^\rho e_\rho$ is a heuristic notation that we see a lot in traditional books. What is the partial derivative of a vector field? I have no idea. (We know what $\partial_\mu V^\nu$ is when $V^\nu$ are the components of a vector field. But that is not what $\partial_\mu e_\nu$ could be.) In contrast: the connection $\nabla$ is the machine that accepts vector   fields $X,Y$ giving $\nabla_XY$ (as MTW work out very pedagogically).

Three other rigorous books that use the MTW $\nabla$ notation are M. Nakahara, Geometry Topology and Physics p. 261 and T. Frankel, Geometry of Physics p. 243, and G. Lugo, Differential Geometry in Physics, p. 191.

@Qmechanic    Operator $d$ can be equivalently expressed as $d=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} dx^\mu$, So he can get metric compatible equation.

If you read John Dirk Walecka's p. 39 very carefully he writes that $d$ is a "first order infinitesimal". Greetings to Newton and Leibniz. Obviously $d$ is not the exterior derivative you want it to be. Even if it were: what is $de_i,?$ ($e_i$ is not a differential form).

@Kurt G.  I think perhaps the operator $d$ is not the exterior derivative, I think it should be treated as a total differential operator. so he write:$$d g_{ij}=\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l}dx^l$$ So here $de_i$ just means an infinitesimal change of basis field $e_i(x)$.

@Kurt G I think it is not impossible to define the partial derivative of a vector field., perhaps we can directly define:$$\partial_\mu V(x)\doteq \lim_{\Delta x^\mu \rightarrow 0}\frac{V(x+\Delta x^\mu)-V(x)}{\partial x^\mu}$$ And  from the first equation we can directly get :$$e_\nu(x+\Delta x^\mu)\approx (I+\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho)e_\rho(x)\Delta x^\mu$$ I wonder what is the relation between $e_\nu(x+\Delta x^\mu)$ and $e_\nu(x)$ from the second equation?
